# Creating semi-automatic hyperlinks to other items in same library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, hyperlink

I have created some pages in the 'Pages' library pertaining to certain content. They have an extra field called 'Description' used to store the summary about the page.

Now, if the description on a page contains the 'Title' of any other page in the library, it should get automatically hyperlinked to that page.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any OOTB solution for this, but what you could do is:

- Create an Event Receiver for `ItemAdded` and `ItemUpdated`.
- Retrieve all items.
- Replace all occurrences of each title (from all items) in the description with a link to the item.
- [Safely update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468156) the item.

Comment: That's a good idea... Unfortunately, I have my hands tied when it comes to using custom code (no Visual Studio, only SP Designer is allowed). I would prefer something closer to OOTB.

Comment: I guess you could do the same with a workflow, although I'm not sure how pretty it would be in SPD. A workflow built with VS on the other hand.

Are you so tied you could not make a sandboxed solution?

Comment: yup..no sandbox solutions. A workflow that is executed every time an item is added or updated and replaces the text in description with hyperlinks to other documents- I wonder if SPD is upto it.

Answer (score 0):

If custom code is not allowed, you can add javascript using content editor web part in the page that can handle this.

You just need to find description data using jQuery/javascript and get data from sharepoint using javascript sharepoint client api and convert appropriate characters to hyperlink.

Let me know if you need more help.